# How to connect to Gmail IMAP through VPN?

Tags: vpn, gmail-imap

Recently, I changed to a shorter mail address(from Google Apps, to Google Apps, just for an address). As I have Google Apps standard version, I have to use 3rd party tools to migrate my two mailboxes.

However, I have a slow connection to imap.gmail.com, and I cannot get some of my mails with big attachments migrated, because before the FETCH command finishes, the server would disconnect me.

I've searched about this, and found that if a client didn't SEND and commands to server within a time limit, the server will make this connection timeout. But actually I'm receiving data, and the tool would not send any commands.

Since my connection cannot finish the transfer in time, I can't get those mails migrated. To accelerate the connection, I tried to use several VPNs, but when I connect, I always get "connect timeout" message. Seems that the connection cannot be established.

How to get it worked? Why can't I connect to Google's IMAP server through VPN?

(Google's IMAP uses SSL on 993 port)

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the server would time-out a connection while sending data through it...

Comment: @grawity  It happens to me sometimes on GMail and large mailboxes with 10+ GiB of mails.

Comment: At last Zimbra servers count timeouts like that, and I'm pretty sure  my experience of Gimap is because of that too...

Comment: I'm using imapsync, a perl script. It always tells me "socket closed while reading data from server" when fetching a big mail.

Comment: If your connection isn't fast enough then adding the overhead of a VPN won't improve things.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason behind using a third party tool? Why don't you use email fetcher to fetch emails from your Gmail account to Google Apps absolutely free.

I have recently migrated 40,000 emails for one of my clients from Yahoo! Small Business to Gmail and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean "email fetcher"? Did you mean "Get mail from other accounts:(Download mail using POP3)"? 
Can it get all the mails including archived? another question is I have joined the same maillist on both mail account... Will it create duplicate mails?